# Updating Checkbox values using workflow

Tags: workflow, field-update, inputcheckboxes

I would like to create a cross object workflow that updates a checkbox value of the child record (with true /false) with the checkbox value of the parent record (true /false) and recalculates every time the child record is edited and saved.

Ie. Value of 'Checkbox1' on Account object must be the same as value of 'Checkbox1' on opportunity object when a new opportunity record is created. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a **workflow rule + field update**, you can make the Checkbox field in the Child object as a **FORMULA Checkbox Field** which directly reads the checkbox value from the Parent. this way everytime the checkbox value on the Parent record changes, the child record get it directly.

- Go to Setup -> Customize -> Opportunities -> Fields
- Create a new custom field
- Select the field type as Formula and Select Return type as Checkbox
- Enter the Formula as the Parent Object Checkbox field name

hope its clear

Comment: Very clear thanks. This above answer resolves the issue that I have specked out perfectly but now I also want the user to be able to modify the checkbox field on the child record. Therefore a formula field will not work in this case.

Ie. When the child record is created I want the checkbox on the child record to be defaulted with whatever is on the parent, but then I want the user the have the ability to manually update the child record.

Comment: Then you have to go with Workflow Rule + Field update. make the checkbox field on the child record as Normal Checkbox field and use a Field Update with Value as Account.CheckBoxFieldName to get the parent checkbox value